# Google sign-in finishedWithAuth gets called only after clicking twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-signin

I am trying to set up `Google` login on my app and I have setup the following function for it:

```
-(void) performGoogleLogin{

GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;

signIn.clientID = kClientId;

signIn.scopes = @[ @"email" ];

signIn.delegate = self;

[signIn authenticate];

}
```

When I do this the first time, the app opens `Safari` where I grant permissions. After returning to my app, this function in my AppDelegate gets called:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

   return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

But then, the `-(void) finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error` function does not get called immediately. It only gets called when I invoke the `performGoogleLogin` function by clicking my button a second time. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a duplicate of [finishedWithAuth not called after authenticate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727342/finishedwithauth-not-called-after-authenticate-method/22670078#22670078)

Make GPPSignIn a class-level variable to avoid it getting garbage collected when the device switches to Safari for the login.