# finishedWithAuth not called after authenticate method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have already set the clientID ,scope and then on button click in MyViewController ,i am calling method login from LoginCLass which works but after   [signIn authenticate] ,the delegate implementation finishedWithAuth is not getting called.I have set .h file as

```
- (NSError *) login
{
    NSLog(@"In login :%@ %@ %@",kClientId,scopes,actions);

    if(!kClientId|| !scopes)
    {
        NSLog(@"Either client ID Or scope is not specified!! ");
        NSError *err=[[NSError alloc]initWithDomain:@"Scope not specified" code:0 userInfo:nil];
       return err;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Client ID and Scope are set.");
        GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
        signIn.delegate = self;
        signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
        [signIn authenticate];
        [signIn trySilentAuthentication];
        return nil;
    }
}
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
}
```

and also in AppDelegate i am adding the code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}
```

I have checked the bundle ID and  URL Types to be specified,they are set same as bundle ID from Google API access.

These methods are in LoginClass which are used in MyViewController class.

When i set the finishedWithAuth delegate to MyViewController ,by setting it as GPPSignInDelegate, the code runs fine.But, i want to use it from LoginClass.

Any idea , where am i going wrong ??

Comment: Found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Since your LoginClass is a Swift class, the fix is to make it a subclass of NSObject.

I had the same issue: when I tried to set the delegate to a class that was not a subclass of NSObject, the assignment failed and the delegate remained nil. When I added NSObject as a superclass, the assignment worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be where an instance of the GPPSignIn is not persisted between leaving the app to load Safari and coming back to your app.

Currently in your login method you have:

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
```

so this is a local instance variable. Try moving this to the class level:

```
@implementation LoginClass {
  GPPSignIn *signIn;
}
```

then use that in your *login* method

Answer (score 2):

You Can use

```
if (![signIn trySilentAuthentication])
        [signIn authenticate];
```

Follow this link for more detail
[trySilentAuthentication without Google+ button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741263/trysilentauthentication-without-google-button)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too in my apps running iOS 8. What did it for me was to set the clientId in the AppDelegate as soon as the app launched, and not in the viewDidLoad method of my UIViewController class as indicated in the Google+ Sign-in for iOS example in the following URL: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
/
//Google+
// Set app's client ID for |GPPSignIn| and |GPPShare|.
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"xxxxxx.......apps.googleusercontent.com";

...

return YES;

}
```

So, in your UIViewController class the sign-in method should be:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//Google+ for Logging in the user again if the app has been authorized
signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
signIn.delegate = self;
[signIn trySilentAuthentication];

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution for this.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if (url.absoluteString.range(of: "oauth2callback") != nil) {
       GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: nil)
    }
   return false
}
```