# Auto login in iOS Swift using Facebook & Google

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, autologin, google-signin

I know this is a design issue and not really a technical one, but it sounds like a very common issue, so I assume it is appropriate for here also.

I have an iOS application (written in Swift) that should support 3 login methods: Facebook, Google & signing up using email & password.

Once user logged in for the first time I want to remember which method he used and login automatically next time the app starts (assuming it didn't stay in background of course).

For Google I can use the following code:

```
let googleSignIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
if googleSignIn.trySilentAuthentication() {
    // was able to login automatically using google
    // no need to show login screen
}
```

This code is UI-independent, meaning I can call it from AppDelegate and know in advance whether I should show login screen or skip automatically to application's main screen.

It looks that the equivalent functionality in Facebook is to have ViewController which implements `FBLoginViewDelegate` protocol, has `FBLoginView` button, and assign itself as delegate to FBLoginView:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBLoginViewDelegate, GPPSignInDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var fbLoginView: FBLoginView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.fbLoginView.delegate = self

     }
 ...
```

For Facebook auto login I can then use the following code in this view controller:

```
func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView : FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser) {
      // logged in automatically using facebook, open main page
 }
```

However, this code is UI-**dependent**, meaning I must instantiate the ViewController, otherwise loginViewFetchedUserInfo callback won't trigger and I won't know that user logged in automatically using Facebook.

Of course if I want to handle the auto-login after user signed up using email & password I need to manage it myself, what I can do in this case is simply save the credentials using `NSUserDefaults`.

Basically I can use the same mechanism also to remember which method the user used to login, but I guess that for Facebook & Google I should still call their appropriate API to actually perform the auto-login.

The issue I'm struggling with is that for Facebook there's no UI-**independent** API like in Google, and I must "pass through" the login screen, although I may not need it eventually.

Another problem is that the Facebook event is triggered asynchronously, so I need to "suspend" the login buttons presentations until it's triggered, although I can know easily that user already logged in to Facebook in the past, by keeping indication using NSUserDefaults, as I do for sign-up case, and I want to do anyway, to know which API I should use to verify the automatic login.

Regarding Google login, it's not clear if the value returned from trySilentAuthentication is enough to verify the login, or if I also need to wait for `GPPSignInDelegate.finishedWithAuth` to trigger, so need to instantiate the LoginView also in this case.

This turned to be a very long question, but again, it sounds like a very common scenario, so hopefully I can get some insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone will encounter a similar issue, the Facebook API I was missing is `FBSession.openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI`.

And this is how my code looks like:

```
class LoginHelper : NSObject, GPPSignInDelegate {

    private let googleClientID = "myClientID"
    private let userDefaultsLoginMethodKey = "LoginMethod"
    private let userDefaultsAppTokenKey = "AppToken"

    var googleSignIn: GPPSignIn

    // google auto login is async, need to save handlers
    var autoLoginCompletionHandler : (() -> Void)?
    var autoLoginErrorHandler : ((err: String) -> Void)?

    class var sharedInstance : LoginHelper {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance : LoginHelper = LoginHelper()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    enum LoginMethod : String {

        case NotLoggedIn = "NotLoggedIn"
        case Facebook = "facebook"
        case Google = "google"
        case MyApp = "MyApp"

        func token() -> String? {
            switch (self) {
            case .Google:
                if LoginHelper.sharedInstance.googleSignIn.authentication != nil {
                    return LoginHelper.sharedInstance.googleSignIn.authentication.accessToken
                }
            case .Facebook:
                if FBSession.activeSession().isOpen {
                    if let tokenData = FBSession.activeSession().accessTokenData {
                        return tokenData.accessToken
                    }
                }
            default:
                return nil
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    var loginMethod : LoginMethod {

        get {
            let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            if let method = defaults.stringForKey(userDefaultsLoginMethodKey) {
                if let loginMethod = LoginMethod(rawValue: method) {
                    return loginMethod
                }
            }
            return LoginMethod.NotLoggedIn
        }
        set {
            let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setValue(newValue.rawValue, forKey: userDefaultsLoginMethodKey)
        }
    }

    var accessToken : String? {

        get {
            let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            if let token = defaults.stringForKey(userDefaultsAppTokenKey) {
                return token
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setValue(newValue, forKey: userDefaultsAppTokenKey)
        }
    }

    private override init() {
        googleSignIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
        googleSignIn.clientID = googleClientID
        googleSignIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
        googleSignIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = true
        googleSignIn.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoEmail]
    }

    func loginToServer(method : LoginMethod, completionHandler : (() -> Void)? = nil, errorHandler : ((err : String) -> Void)? = nil) {
        if let token = loginMethod.token() {
            // login to server with token
        }
    }

    func autoLogin(completionHandler : () -> Void, errorHandler : (err : String) -> Void) {

        switch (loginMethod) {

        case .Google:

            googleSignIn.delegate = self
            if googleSignIn.trySilentAuthentication() {
                // actual login will occur when finishedWithAuth is triggered, 
                // keep completionHandler & errorHandler to be used later
                autoLoginCompletionHandler = completionHandler
                autoLoginErrorHandler = errorHandler
            } else {
                errorHandler(err: "silent authentication failed for Google")
            }

        case .Facebook:
            if FBSession.openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI(false) {
                loginToServer(loginMethod, completionHandler: completionHandler, errorHandler: errorHandler)
            } else {
                errorHandler(err: "failed to login automaticlly to Facebook")
            }
        default:
            Logger.debug("Skip server login for \(loginMethod.rawValue)")
            completionHandler()
        }
    }

    func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication,  error: NSError! ) -> Void {
        if let err = error {
            Logger.error("Failed to login with Google")
            autoLoginErrorHandler?(err: "failed to login automaticlly to Google")
        } else {
            // login to server
            loginToServer(LoginMethod.Google, completionHandler: autoLoginCompletionHandler, errorHandler: autoLoginErrorHandler)
        }
    }

    func didDisconnectWithError(error: NSError!) -> Void{
    }

}
```

Notice that LoginHelper **must** extends NSObject, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727342/finishedwithauth-not-called-after-authenticate-method).